# JVM keeps calling garbage collector for no apparent reason

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, max-heap

While testing MaxFreeHeapRatio and MinFreeHeapRatio I found the following situation:

[Application heap profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM3Dy.png)

[Garbage collector activity profiling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHBYA.png)

So, the JVM keep executing the garbage collector even though there is lots of free memory available.

I'm using the following flags:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx15636m
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:MinHeapFreeRation=20
```

Any idea of the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Not sure if I am thinking right. Serial GC and Parallel GC are long pause garbage collections.

This means if there is a lot to collect and the frequency of collection is less, it might end up pausing for long time while collection.

Hence, I think it is logical to have frequent small collects (as it will pause for lesser time) and that is what it might be doing.

Comment: Is your tenured space more than 20% full?

Comment: charts omit way too much information. Enable `-XX:+PrintGCDetails`, inspect the GC logs, they should inform you about the GC cause. `-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC` may help too.

Comment: Is it meant to be `MinHeapFreeRation` or `MinHeapFreeRatio`?